# Nth prime for which a property holds is endlessly asking me for input

Tags: c, floating-point, primes

I have to make a program that reads from the input an integer `n`. Some prime numbers have the property that the sum of all the prime numbers up to and including `p` is a prime too. The output must be the nth number for which this property holds. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int squareRoot(int x) {
    float sqrt, temp = 0;
    sqrt = x / 2;
    while (sqrt != temp) {
        temp = sqrt;
        sqrt = (x / temp + temp) / 2;
    }
    return sqrt;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int n, count = 0, flag = 0, sumPrime = 0;
    scanf("%d", &n);

    while (count != n) {
        for (int p = 2; p <= 196831; p++) {
            for (int i = 2; i <= squareRoot(p); i++) {
                if (p % i == 0) {
                    flag = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (flag == 0) {
                sumPrime += p;
                for (int e = 2; e <= squareRoot(sumPrime); e++) {
                    if (sumPrime % e == 0) {
                        flag = 1;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (flag == 0)
                    count++;
            }
            flag = 0;
        }
    }
    printf("%d", sumPrime);
    return 0;
}
```

If I compile and run it, it is endlessly asking for input.

Does anyone know why? Because I think my code is fine except for the endless input.

Comment: Use a debugger, discover that the program *hangs* in the while loop in squareRoot().  So it only looks like it asks for input.  Never test a floating point value for equality.

Comment: Did you write `scanf("%d ", &n);` with a space after the `d`?  That will hang waiting for you to type a character that isn't white space (and newlines count as white space), or until you indicate EOF.  It's good practice to end output lines with a newline: `printf("%d\n", sumPrime);`.  Also, since you use your own, home grown `squareRoot()` function, there's no need to include `<math.h>`, is there?  It's also quicker to compute `i * i <= p` and `e * e <= sumPrime` than to call any square root function.

Comment: It is not safe to use `scanf` without checking the return value. See this page for further information: [A beginners' guide away from scanf()](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I used i * i <= p and also for e, still doesn't work. I checked everythink else you said but it still ask me for input endlessly.

Comment: Waddya mean by "it still asks me for input endlessly"? There's a single `scanf()`. Either it returns a value, or it doesn't return because it is waiting for input. There's no loop around the input.  Presumably, the program also doesn't output anything if it is waiting endlessly for input. Are you sure you're running the program whose code you show?  Did you recompile? Add `printf("N = %d\n", n);` after the `scanf()`? Add `printf("Enter n: "); fflush(stdout);` before the `scanf()`. Add `printf("count = %d\n", count);` and `printf("p = %d\n", p);` as the first statement in the loop bodies?

Comment: `i * i <= p` can overflow for large primes.  Use `i <= p/i`.

Comment: When I run the code with the printing added, and I enter `1` as the value for `n`, I get a lot of printing of `p = 104059` etc, and eventually it hangs.  The problem is not the input; the problem is the algorithm — it doesn't terminate correctly.  I found the lines — `p = 196831` — `count = 1000` — `p = 2` — at one point in the output. One of the most basic debugging techniques is to print the values you read. Another is to print the status of calculations as you proceed.  The code I used did not include changes to the loop conditions — it only added printing and testing that `scanf()` was OK.

Comment: OT: regarding; `sqrt`  the math.h library contains the function: `sqrt()`  It is a VERY POOR practice to use variable names that are the same as a function name in an included library

Comment: @user3629249 I am not allowed to use any of the math.h functions :(

Comment: regarding: *I am not allowed to use any of the math.h functions*  then don't include the `math.h` header file

Comment: Niek van de Wouw, for this task `sqrt()` from math.h or your own is not needed.  `i <= p/i` is sufficient.

Comment: (to your recent question, [see this](https://gist.github.com/WillNess/09014efb3b9a715c55789bd39caafae4))

Answer (score 3):

There are some problems in your code:

- the `squareRoot` function probably has an infinite loop because the end test never succeeds. Using the `float` type for this computation causes `sqrt` and `temp` to potentially always differ by a minuscule amount.  You should use the floating point function `sqrt()` from `<math.h>` or better not compute the square root at all.
- in the loop `for (int i = 2; i <= squareRoot(p); i++)` you recompute `squareRoot(p)` at every iteration, which is **very** inefficient. It would be much faster to either

  - compute `squareRoot(p)` once at the beginning of the loop, or
  - write `for (int i = 2; i <= p / i; i++)`
- you do not test if `count == n` inside the second loop, when you iterate over primes, so you let `count` increment well beyond `n` and never break from the outer loop.
- there is no reason to stop at `196831`.

Here is a modified version using an `isPrime()` function to simplify the code:

```c
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int isPrime(int n) {
    for (int i = 2; i <= n / i; i++) {
        if (n % i == 0)
            return 0;
    }
    return n >= 2;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int n, count = 0, sumPrime = 0;

    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1 || n < 0) {
        printf("invalid input\n");
        return 1;
    }
    for (int p = 2;; p++) {
        if (isPrime(p)) {
            if (sumPrime > INT_MAX - p) {
                printf("out of range\n");
                return 1;
            }
            sumPrime += p;
            if (isPrime(sumPrime)) {
                count++;
                if (n == 0 || count == n) {
                    printf("%d: %d\n", p, sumPrime);
                    if (n != 0)
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

PS: you can enumerate the prime sums of primes by entering `0` at the prompt. `int` type is large enough for the first 1103 such primes in 0.3 seconds. Type `long` or `long long` can be used to find larger ones, (ie 10000 giving 3420293: 402638678093 in 30 seconds) but the search becomes quite slow for larger numbers as the complexity seems worse than **O(n<sup>2</sup>)**, possibly **O(n<sup>3</sup>)**.

Comment: It is still not giving the correct output, but I think I am able to figure it out now. Thanks!

Comment: @NiekvandeWouw: what are the input value and the expected output? You output `sumPrime` but you might be expected to output `p` instead.

Comment: For `isprime()` perhaps `return 1;` --> `return n >= 2;` for proper functionality when `n < 2`? - not that calling code ever calls it with such a small `n`, but better as a stand-alone function.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: good point. There are many ways to improve this function :)